# Interpolation with Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a sparsely filled Dataframe with continous dates as index. I want to interpolate my data between the known points.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

rng = pd.date_range('2015,1,1', periods=10, freq='d')
data = [[datetime.datetime(2015,1,1),0,0],[datetime.datetime(2015,1,10),5, 10]]
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':None, 'b':None , 'c':None}, index=rng)
for each in data:
    df.ix[each[0]] = each

df.interpolate()
```

The `df.interpolate()` gives me the error message:

> TypeError: Cannot interpolate with all NaNs.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.